# Converting greek utf letters to latex symbols

Tags: unicode, greek

I have a collection of notes on my iPad, written using a markdown editor/viewer (trunk notes) that does not understand latex, but does display greek. Is there a simple way to convert the greek letters (e.g. convert the UTF-8 symbol 0xCEB1, α) to their latex equivalents (`\alpha`)? I am using pandoc for the conversion, which is pasting a LaTeX header onto the output before conversion to TeX or ConTeXt.

Comment: Do you need them also in text or only in math?

Comment: Both. I'm placing some short notes inline, and putting longer equations in center /center  tags. The app doesn't understand latex, so I am displaying it as HTML on the iPad, but would like to  translate the notes to LaTex on my computer. One path is markdown->html->pdf, but that is rather ugly.

Answer (score 3):

In ConTeXt (both MkIV and MkII with utf-8 encoding), Greek letters work out of the box in text and math mode. (You need a text font with Greek letters)

```
\starttext
α $α$
\stoptext
```

With MkIV, Unicode characters behave like ASCII characters, so `$\hat α$` is same as `$\hat {α}$`. In MkII, you need to use the latter form.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code to make unicode symbols work both as normal text and in mathmode. But then `xelatex` is needed to compile it:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{STIXGeneral}

\def\textalpha{α} \catcode`\α=\active \defα{\relax\ifmmode \alpha \else \textalpha \fi}
```

Also you need some suitable font, STIX works for me.

If you want to actually replace the unicode characters in the source code, that is a different issue. I don't know what kind of tools are available in your environment. I would compile a list of replacements like `α \alpha` and then write a small script that executes those in order. E.g. there is the `replace` utility on linux which does one such replacement.

Comment: `\usepackage{newunicodechar}` and then `\newunicodechar{α}{\ifmmode\alpha\else α\fi}` is easier. :) However, with `unicode-math` and XITS Math as math font (also with other fonts, I believe) it works out of the box.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for the hint. Of course as I only have to do this once in some custom package, it is not really an effort. Still having it work out of the box would be great. I actually did this when `unicode-math` didn't work properly yet. Also, pmav99 uses the `xgreek` package, is that necessary?

Comment: No it is not. I just copy pasted...! I'll remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding Canaaerus answer In xelatex, package `unicode-math` allows you to use greek characters in math-mode. Check the following minimum example.

```
\documentclass{article}

% font selection for normal text
\usepackage{fontspec}

% Packages needed for mathematics
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

% Fonts
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    a = α + b + β^2_i
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

For more info (in greek) look [here](http://www.mechpedia.gr/wiki/LaTeX)

### Fonts

The fonts that you may use are the following ones (they must be installed in your OS' standard font folder)

- [Asana-Math](http://ctan.org/pkg/asana-math). Free font created by Apostolos Syropoulos.
- [Stix](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/stix)
- [Xits](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xits), fork of Stix
- [Neo Euler](http://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf)
- [Latin Modern Math](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/index_html), OpenType version of the classic TeX font.
- Cambria Math. Proprietary font, distributed with Microsoft software (e.g. MS Office)

### Edit

Note though that `a` and `\alpha` are different symbols! If you want to convert `α` to `a`then the previous approach cannot be used. If that is what you need, then it shouldn't be too difficult to write a script (e.g. in perl or python) that would parse your notes and make the replacements.

Comment: Your links to Stix and Xits do not work. Maybe you mean http://www.ctan.org/pkg/stix and http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xits ?

Comment: Thank you. I was copy-pasting that too. I will fix them.

Comment: Do greek letters also work in text mode with lualatex/fontspec/unicode-math?

Comment: @Aditya I am not really sure. In principle, I believe they should but I am not a LuaLaTeX user. I am mostly interested in multilingual texts. Last time I tried, LuaLaTeX had some problems with greek, so I haven't spend time with it.